# Self-Destruct function able to restore tokens?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, etherscan

I sent tokens to etherscan contract address which can be triggered to send them back to the sender's address probably. Can someone help me out with that to do so? Need every help out there :/
Would accept giving a reward when helped successfully. Thank you
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9cd088eac047b6ba5f9ec6691b49bf907ae138898ca329bcd8c69cc3eeacbd5a

Answer (score 0):

Self-destruct function only works if it has been implemented before the deployment and it can only recover the ethers, on top of that the ethers can only be recovered to an address that has been mentioned inside the contract before deployment.

In your case it's an ERC20 token, that can only be taken out if the contract has some functionality to transfer tokens.